# Phone GAP SessionStorage

Tags: iphone, cordova

I working on an iPhone Application using phone GAP.In my app we are using an external DB .User login using web service, i need to store user ID after login .How i store the user ID using phone GAP.can i use phone GAP Session Storage for this?is possible?

Any one knows please helps.

Thanks,
Companion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You really don't have the concept of "session" in Phonegap - you have HTML5 localStorage to store persistent data (think "application scope"):

```
var userId = localStorage.getItem("userId");
if (userId==null || userId==0) {
    jQT.goTo("#login"); 
}
```

Log user in:

```
$('#btnLogin').click(function(){
$("#loginFailure").hide();
$.getJSON(svcUri + "authenticate.cfm?username="+$("#username").val()+"&password="+$("#password").val() + "&callback=?",function(data) {
  localStorage.setItem("userId",data.userid);
  userId = data.userid;
  if (data.userid != 0) {
   // do some tasks after logging in
   jQT.goTo('#travelz');  
  } else {
   $("#loginFailure").show();
  }
  });
 return false;
```

});

Comment: using a GET request isn't the way to do login. It's too vulnerable. Use a POST request instead, over SSL to be safe.

Comment: "You really don't have the concept of "session" in Phonegap" - this is not correct

Answer (score 9):

Lawnchair is probably overkill just to store and ID, just use HTML5 [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

Answer (score 3):

You could try [lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/) to store data as JSON.

Comment: Side benefit to this is that you can then easily port to other PhoneGap platforms that won't necessarily support a specific offline storage mechanism.
Kris' suggestion below is correct (I upvoted it!) but a more robust solution would be to employ Lawnchair for future use of the app on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

There *is* a concept of SessionStorage. It works the same way as localStorage, but gets erased every time you close the application

```
var keyName = window.sessionStorage.key(0); //Get key name
window.sessionStorage.setItem("key", "value"); //Set item
var value = window.sessionStorage.getItem("key");// Get item
window.sessionStorage.removeItem("key"); //Remove Item 
window.sessionStorage.clear();//Clear storage
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set session storage like that

```
var userid = 10;
sessionStorage.setItem('UserId',userid);
```

You will get this session variable like that

```
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('UserId');
```

Note: This variable will reset after close app but if you wants to save on localstorage then you need localStorage function which will not reset after close app