# Sending an AJAX call before all other AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to check for a condition and run an AJAX call before sending other AJAX calls on my web app.

I was thinking about putting this AJAX call in a **beforeSend** on **ajaxSetup** with async: false (to prevent my initial call from running before this one has completed).

Something like this:

```
//I set an event that fires:
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: my_url,
    beforeSend: function() {
        //do something, like show a spinner loader gif
    }
});

//Somehwere in my app I also have:
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function() {
        if(x===1){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: my_url/fetch_something,
                async:false
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Will my beforeSend on the first AJAX call overrun the one in the ajaxSetup? Is there a way to approach this better?

Better idea of my app:

I have a lot of Ajax calls through the app, each call sends a security hash on the headers to validate the user, these hashes have a time limit as well (both hash and time limit are saved in localStorage)

What I want from ajax setup (and the condition in it) is to check for the time limit - if time_limit < current_time than run an ajax call to refresh the users hash.

This isn't an exercise for 1 or 2 calls, I literally have 20+ growing Ajax calls on my app that make use of the users hash and it's very impractical to make this check in every single one of them.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't handle the functionality of the initial ajax call on the initial page load?

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED:

Have one method on an interval that sets up the 'session'/local-storage

```
var refreshing = false;
var intervalID;
$(document).ready(function(e){
   var delay = 1234;
   intervalID = window.setInterval(setupInterval, delay);
});

function setupInterval(){
  refreshing = true;
  $.ajax(URL).done(function(r) { //do stuff
    setupStorage(r);
    refreshing = false;
  });
}
function setupStorage(info){
  //setup whatever here
}
```

OLD:

Could you use some logic in your ready function to gate what you need to do?

So basically call one ajax call -> if false, just schedule your latter methods, otherwise run the setup one and on completion schedule the latter method.

Some pseudo-code:

```
var refresh = false;
$(document).ready(function(e){
   $.ajax(URL).done( function(r) { 
       if(r) {
        routeOne();
       } else {
        latter();
       }
     });
});

function routeOne(){
  $.ajax(URL).done(function(r) { //do stuff
    latter();
  });
}
function latter(){
  //All other ajax calls
}
```

I'll put some more thought into this let me finish my coffee first...

EDIT:

Based on your updated description could it be possible for you to schedule a setInterval to run the checking method/hash update on the time interval that you need, and is the time interval on your server static or variable? Facebook does this with a heartbeat, I've used this type of logic with some 'locking' functionality in a web-app. If you schedule the interval properly it should not interrupt any other ajax calls.

Comment: I updated my answer a bit, but I think DustMason's comment makes a lot of sense.. you want to avoid authentication on the client side. Maybe I'm missing something but you should probably just set up session variables and use that for authenticating the user.  Sessions can have timeouts and you could combine the session with a heartbeat to have the best of both worlds here.

Comment: I am working on an hybrid mobile app though, no access at all to sessions.

Comment: @JoaoFerreira when you say hybrid mobile app do you mean PhoneGap, etc.? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601174/phone-gap-sessionstorage

Comment: After re-reading the question again, I deleted my previous comment :) I see that you are already sending along the user auth credentials with each request anyway. With this is mind, what do you gain at all security-wise by allowing the client to continuously request new auth tokens without re-signing in? It seems to me that with this design you are already sidestepping any gains you might have by using expiring tokens. An attacker could simply keep requesting fresh ones.

Comment: I was under the impression that "You really don't have the concept of "session" in Phonegap - you have HTML5 localStorage to store persistent data (think "application scope")", the problem is, I have to work with time limit based hashes, I'm simply looking for the best way to refresh this hash in javascript. Such a thing would be easy enough server side, construct parameters and whatnot to sniff out stuff like this and setting sessions/cookies on the fly. But right now I am expected to ASK the server for a new hash, have this hash returned to me, and set it up again in localStorage.

Comment: @JoaoFerreira I think I understand better now, I fall back to my heartbeat idea.. just write a function that sets everything up in local storage so that the other AJAX calls just get the data from local storage agnostic as to what put it there, and assume it is time-valid. So every X seconds you have your setup heartbeat run, that way if they "log off" for more than X seconds, they become invalid and need to re-auth. Any AJAX calls will just query local storage for what they need, not knowing the heartbeat is updating the data for them.

Comment: What params do you need to pass the server in order to get a fresh hash back, and how long do these things typically take to expire?

Comment: DustMason, you bring an interesting point (I'm not responsible for this "refreshing hash" idea), hashes last for 24h, to validate a user we send his login credentials over - email and password,we have this stored in localStorage (again, I'm not the biggest fan of this, not really in my control), this validates the user and returns me a new hash. I'm 1 step away from suggesting SSL (not entirely sure if we can do this in Phonegap) and simply have one hash that doesn't refresh at all... maybe only once on re-login in or something.

Comment: Also, considering refreshing the hash on app resume (I don't think anyone runs an app for 24h on the screen...)

Comment: @JoaoFerreira I agree with DustMason, it seems like a design flaw I just provided a hack to do it, but SSL is a better bet, and its not too bad with PG. Provided you have valid certs.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560881/does-phonegap-support-https-ajax-requests

Comment: Zach, your set interval solution sounds interesting, but I can't run on the chance of it triggering during other ajax calls in my app, it is my understanding that there is a limit to how many AJAX calls you can run at the same time.

Comment: I understand that you are working with some external restrictions, but I would say that an app which stores user credentials in plain text, then sends them over the wire unencrypted every day is insecure (and would break the rules for most commercial APIs!). SSL is a must if you can't get around the other issues. If the API you are using also allows something like OAuth you can skirt this issue entirely!

Comment: @JoaoFerreira that's why I included the refreshing boolean variable you could check for that on other AJAX calls. But I still think DustMason has the right answer.

Comment: Thank you for your input guys, plenty of food for thought.

Comment: One last thing, I have little to no experience with OAuth, but how could this work on a pure Javascript app? The user always has to download the app, and I would need to set things like tokenSecret on the JS files, wouldn't this defeat the purpose of OAuth?

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding $.ajax to make a "pre-call" before passing in your given query options:

```
var oldAjax = $.ajax;

$.ajax = function() {

  var args = arguments;

  oldAjax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/echo/html/",
    success: function(result){
      // do something here to check result
      // if result is good, do the request:
      return oldAjax.apply($, args);
      // if its bad, handle the error
    }
  });

}
```

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/NF76U/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the use of `.done()` ( `$.Deferred` `object`)

```
function AjaxCall() {
 return //code of your ajax without async:false
}

function anotherAjaxCall{
 return //code of you ajax call
}


AjaxCall.done(anotherAjaxCall);
```

Avoid using `async:false` it's a deprecated practice and it stucks browsers